# Adjusting the volume of a specific audio device from the command line

Tags: macos, audio

I'd like to adjust the volume of a specific audio device from the command line in OS X. All examples of this that I can find are for the *active* audio device using osascript, which doesn't appear to let you specify specific hardware.

I'm specifically looking to adjust the volume of something that /isn't/ the active output device, the same way I can manually do so by opening Audio MIDI Setup, selecting "USB Audio Device", and dragging the sliders.

Answer (score 2):

There is an NPM package with a CLI to do this: https://github.com/karaggeorge/macos-audio-devices

Before I found it, I also found the following, which still can be suitable if Node.js can not be used for some reason.

1. There is a tool, likely not actively developed, to do this exactly: https://github.com/jonomuller/device-volume-adjuster.
2. There is a chance to adjust (get/set) volume of active output via AppleScript: `osascript -e "output volume of (get volume settings)"` to get and `osascript -e "set volume output volume ..."` to set.
3. There is a tool, under active development, to switch devices: https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx.

So likely the proper solution could be to use (1), but it can require bringing (1) project back to life. Maybe it will work or build without any problems, I did not try.

And the tricky solution, which should work without problems, but at the cost of temporary audio silencing, can be combining (2) and (3): use (3) to get active device, then to switch to another, then (2) to adjust volume, than again (3) to return back to initial device.